# How to check CHMOD using BASH (numeric)?

Tags: bash

How can I check `chmod` in bash?
How can I check that user, group... have 7 (R-W-X) ? Or 4 etc ?

```
#!/bin/bash  
.
.
for file in *
do

if [ $file check.... ? ]
then
     echo $file
fi

done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you want is `stat`:

```
$ touch /tmp/file

# permissions + filename
$ stat -c "%a %n" /tmp/file
644 /tmp/file

# just file permissions
$ stat -c "%a" /tmp/file 
644

# human readable format
$ stat -c "%A" /tmp/file
-rw-r--r--
```

See `man stat` for the full feature set.

Comment: Thank you. And.. it possible to get ONLY for USER?

Comment: For a file you could do `stat -c "%a" /tmp/file | cut -c1`

Answer (score 0):

For the most common tasks you can use the builtin `[ ... ]` test, `man test`.

This doesn't allow fine grained checking, but that's rarely what you need, usually you only care whether a file exists, readable, etc...

```
-r FILE
       FILE exists and read permission is granted
-w FILE
       FILE exists and write permission is granted
....
```

E.g.:

```
if [ -r $file ]; then
   ..
fi
```